# chrome autocomplete works strange

Tags: html, autocomplete

My initial html is

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="password" name="confirm_password">
</form>
```

when hovering the password it shows a dropdown with previously used password in the site and automatically fills the adjacent lastname with email field.

i tried adding autocomplete="off", autocomplete="new-password" in the password field

```
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

still it doesn't work and fills the lastname field with email address